# Unknown record property / related component "primary_keys" form embed/m:n relationship

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many

I have this schema:

```
JosUsers:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    username: { type: string(150), notnull: true }
    email: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    password: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    usertype: { type: string(25), notnull: true }
    block: { type: integer(1), notnull: true }
    sendemail: { type: integer(1), notnull: false }
    gid: { type: integer(1), default: '1', notnull: true }
    registerdate: { type: timestamp(25), notnull: true }
    lastvisitdate: { type: timestamp(25), notnull: true }
    activation: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    params: { type: string(), notnull: true }
  relations:
    AccessControlObject: { class: JosCoreAclAro, local: id, foreign: value, foreignType: one }

JosCoreAclAro:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4),fixed: false, unsigned: false, primary: true, autoincrement: true}
    section_value: { type: string(240), notnull: true }
    value: {type: string(240), notnull: true }
    order_value: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    hidden: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  relations: 
    Group: { class: JosCoreAclAroGroups, local: aro_id, foreign: group_id, refClass: JosCoreAclGroupsAroMap,foreignType: one }

JosCoreAclGroupsAroMap:
  columns:
    group_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
    section_value: { type: string(240) }
    aro_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
  relations: 
    JosCoreAclAro: { class: JosCoreAclAro, local: aro_id, onDelete: CASCADE }
    JosCoreAclAroGroup: { class: JosCoreAclAroGroups, local: group_id, onDelete: CASCADE }

JosCoreAclAroGroups:
  columns:
    id: {type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    parent_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    lft: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    rgt: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    value: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
```

When I embed JosCoreAclAroForm like this

```
class JosUsersForm extends BaseJosUsersForm{
    public function configure(){


        $josCoreAclAroForm = new JosCoreAclAroForm();
                $this->embedForm('josCoreAclAro', $josCoreAclAroForm);

    }



}
```

I get Unknown record property / related component "primary_keys" on "JosCoreAclAroGroups"

I can't figure out why there this function is called, nor can I find it anywhere?

Comment: This seems to be doctrine checking for the primary key of the object. This is in the Doctrine framework. Did you check your log ? I don't know the "embedForm" method in symfony, are you using version 1.4 or trying version 2 ?

Comment: getPrimaryKeys is in DoctrineCollection, however the model Class JosCoreAclAroGroups is not a descendant of DoctrineCollection

Comment: I found that creating function getPrimaryKeys(){ return array('group_id','aro_id');} solves the problem, but I'm unsure if it will save correctly. Comments on the web say there may be a problem with RefClass having a composite primary key?

Comment: I just tried a single field primary key, same error message

Comment: A class name should be singular, and since doctrine makes many guesses based on whether names end with s or not, this could be the source of your problem, the s at the end of JosCoreAclAroGroups might be misinterpreted somewhere.

Comment: Thanks greg0ire, that was the problem!

Comment: I can't find anything in the code regarding this singular/plural thing, but I'm glad everything went right for you. If anyone knows where this actually happens, I'm interested.

Comment: one more question, am I supposed to edit my original question to make it right? Or post a solution myself?

Comment: @jdog : you're supposed to post a solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg0ire had the answer: "A class name should be singular, and since doctrine makes many guesses based on whether names end with s or not, this could be the source of your problem, the s at the end of JosCoreAclAroGroups might be misinterpreted somewhere."